# Footable jquery plugin not working with asp.net Gridview and pagination

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview, footable

I am using Masterpage with content place holder, inside i am generating my Gridview.

I am using Footable Jquery plugin in order to render it responsive. But when i use the pagination option of the Gridview i loose the footable css and js functionality.

**aspx page**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/www/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="articleListing.aspx.cs" Inherits="www_articleListing" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-footable/0.1.0/css/footable.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-footable/0.1.0/js/footable.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID%>').footable();
    });
</script>
<link href="../css/article.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" CssClass="footable" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="id_article" 
    data-page-size="10" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowSorting="True" AllowPaging="True">
    <Columns>
        <%--<asp:CommandField ShowCancelButton="False" ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />--%>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" ButtonType="Image" ControlStyle-Width="16px" EditImageUrl="../Images/icons/edit-button.png" ItemStyle-Width="25px" UpdateText="Edit" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true" ButtonType="Image" ControlStyle-Width="16px" DeleteImageUrl="../Images/icons/delete-button.png" ItemStyle-Width="25px" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="id_article" HeaderText="#" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="id_article" Visible="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="article_title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="article_title" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="article_writer" HeaderText="Writer" SortExpression="article_writer" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="article_date" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="article_date" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="article_time" HeaderText="Time" SortExpression="article_time" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnStr1 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [id_article], [article_title], [article_writer], [article_date], [article_time] FROM [articles] ORDER BY [article_date] DESC, [article_time] DESC"></asp:SqlDataSource>

<a class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all" id="newArticleBTN" href="addArticle.aspx">New article</a>
</asp:Content>
```

**C# page**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;

public partial class www_articleListing : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindGrid();
    }
}

private void BindGrid()
{
    //Attribute to show the Plus Minus Button.
    GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Attributes["data-class"] = "expand";

    //Attribute to hide column in Phone.
    GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[4].Attributes["data-hide"] = "phone";
    GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[5].Attributes["data-hide"] = "phone";
    GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[6].Attributes["data-hide"] = "phone";

    //Adds THEAD and TBODY to GridView.
    GridView1.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
  }
}
```

**Masterpage header**

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="www_MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title> </title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>
<link href="../css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">       </script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

[**First page look like that**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HafYK.png)

[**After clicking on the pagination the page look like**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLdJs.png)

didn't found any working solution for that issue, please help

Answer (score 1):

Try calling the `footable` function again after pagination or sorting.

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "footable", "$('#" + GridView1.ClientID + "').footable();", true);
}
```

If that does not work, remove the `IsPostBack` check. The problem lies with this line `GridView1.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;`. That needs to be executed every time, whereas the states of `GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[4].Attributes["data-hide"] = "phone";` etc are maintained after postback.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindGrid();

    //or

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindGrid();
    }
    GridView1.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
}
```

Comment: tried it, still not working
I added this on aspx:
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" CssClass="footable" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="id_article" onpageindexchanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging"
        data-page-size="10" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowSorting="True" AllowPaging="True">

And your function on code behind

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry, tried both cases, not working
Any other ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I don't. When I copied your entire snippet I got the same result when using paging. Adding `GridView1.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;` to the page load fixed it for me.